# gmapping with navigation

Tags: ros, gmapping-demo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to do a project on SLAM Gmapping (turtlebot2,kobuki base,ros-hydro) and I'm really blocked I need your help;
actually my task is to navigate the TurtleBot  and avoid obstacles and at the same time make carthographie.
I follow the tutorial of stack navigation and after I realized that in that case I should not work with AMCL and map_server.
So as a first step I tried to build the map,at the beginning it worked but after it didn't, I didn't  know the reason, I find in rviz message: No map received.
here are the steps I did:
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
rosrun tf (laser-->base_link)
rosrun tf (odom-->base_link)
roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch

*the launch file of gmapping_demo.launch :*

**

*the xml file of gmapping:*

```
<param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
<param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
<param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
<param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
<param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
<remap from="scan" to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
```

*the xml file of move_base:*

```
<remap from="cmd_vel" to="navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel"/>
<remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
```

and the configuration of costmap parametrs:

*costmap_common_parametrs.yaml:*

obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.20
footprint: [[-0.16, -0.16], [-0.16, 0.16], [0.16, 0.16], [0.16, -0.16]]
footprint_padding: 0.01
inflation_radius: 0.5
max_obstacle_height: 0.6
min_obstacle_height: 0.0
observation_sources: scan bump
scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
bump: {data_type: PointCloud2, topic: mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud, marking: true, clearing: false, min_obstacle_height: 0.0, max_obstacle_height: 0.15}

*local_costmap_param:*

local_costmap:
global_frame: /odom
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 2.0
static_map: false
rolling_window: true
width: 6.0
height: 6.0
resolution: 0.05
*global_costmap_param:*

globasl_costmap:
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
static_map: true

*base_local_planner_param*:

controller_frequency: 3.0
recovery_behavior_enabled: true
clearing_rotation_allowed: true

*TrajectoryPlannerROS:*
max_vel_x: 0.3
min_vel_x: 0.1
max_vel_theta:  1.0
min_vel_theta: -1.0
min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.6
acc_lim_x: 0.5
acc_lim_theta: 1.0
yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3
xy_goal_tolerance: 0.15
sim_time: 3.0
vx_samples: 6
vtheta_samples: 20
meter_scoring: true
pdist_scale: 0.6
gdist_scale: 0.8
occdist_scale: 0.01
heading_lookahead: 0.325
dwa: true
oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05

holonomic_robot: false
sim_granularity: 0.025
dwa: true
simple_attractor: false

I await your response
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205404/gmapping-with-navigation/) by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you and I are working on nearly the same project.  I am using the Pioneer3-DX and Microsoft Kinect rather than TurtleBot with laser scanner.  I'll post what I have and hopefully it will help.

I followed this tutorial: [Navigation - Robot Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup)
I also followed the video in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack) to help me set up RViz so I can send navigation goals to the robot and visualize him moving to the goal while building the map.
And this tutorial to build a map: [Gmapping - Building a map from logged data](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData)

It looks as if you are doing everything correctly, starting your robot launch files, then your move_base.launch file.

Again, I recommend taking a look at the Navigation - Robot Setup tutorial.  It is very straightforward, and while it is not specific for the Turtlebot, it should work with any robot.  The turtlebot packages should take care of odometry, sensor, and tf (unless you need to add sensors) information.

I am still playing with the parameters to tune his navigation better.  [Long process...](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide)

Here is my move_base.launch:

```
<launch>

  <!-- Start gmapping -->
    <node  pkg="gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" output="screen" />

  <!-- Start navigation -->
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params_p3dx.yaml" ns="global_costmap" />
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params_p3dx.yaml" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" />
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" />
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find follow_me_2dnav)/launch/base_local_planner_params.yaml" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

costmap_common_params.yaml:

```
obstacle_range: 4.0
raytrace_range: 5.0
inflation_radius: 0.5

footprint: [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4] ]

transform_tolerance: 0.5
expected_update_rate: 60
map_type: costmap

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: kinect_depth_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, expected_update_rate: 0.2}
```

global_costmap_params.yaml:

```
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 2.0
publish_frequency: 10.0
static_map: true
```

local_costmap_params.yaml:

```
global_frame: /odom
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 10.0
static_map: false
rolling_window: true
width: 7.5
height: 7.5
resolution: 0.05
```

base_local_planner_params.yaml

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.6
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_rotational_vel: 0.5
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.3
  escape_vel: -0.2

  sim_time: 2.0
  path_distance_bias: 0.7
  goal_distance_bias: 0.5
  occdist_scale: 0.05
  meter_scoring: true

  acc_lim_th: 2.0
  acc_lim_x: 2.0
  acc_lim_y: 2.0

  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25

  holonomic_robot: false
```

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-21**:
Try to use comments, rather than an answer, unless you have the real answer...

You can edit your question or add updates to it instead.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-21**:
I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for or the changes you made to gmapping_demo.launch.  But you can find the files you need [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/launch).

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-21**:
The parameter files are [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/param).

The move_base.launch.xml and gmapping.launch.xml are [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes).

Hope that helps.

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-23**:
thank you very much I checked the files you sent me
they look like my files
but I still had the same problem
I'll explain better my problem

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-23**:
I want build a map exactly like this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM
so  I am writing:

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-23**:
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-23**:
but what I did not understand when I "roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch"
[INFO] [1427123086.980804765]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[INFO] [1427123087.085777796]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[INFO] [1427123087.220729356]: Requesting the map ...

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-23**:
as if he wait for a map while I'll build a map!! and the rviz screnn shows a warning "no map received"

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-23**:
Looking at the [turtlebot_navigation](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/launch), it does not seem like it should be looking for a map.

Try this: [RViz](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack)

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-23**:
To make a map using teleop, I used this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData).

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-24**:
apparently it's a XnSensorServer server problem,
sometimes require a reboot for it to work.
ust one question after having set the parameters of costmap_common_params.yaml
the TurtleBot will avoid obstacles? or I need to configure this to detect and avoid obstacles?

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-24**:
I have added these two lines in the code that I have done in the tutorial of navigation stack for "transformation":
include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS costmap("my_costmap", tf);
I found it in this in this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-24**:
But apparently it's insuffisent , i think that i must do something else for my robot to detect obstacles,
have you any idea about this?

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-24**:
I recommend you give this [Navigation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) a try.  I followed it and the robot is able to detect and avoid obstacles as well as simultaneously build a map.  I'll add my parameter files in my answer.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-24**:
Also, here is additional information on [costmap_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) and [base_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner).